# Trying to read preferences upon BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android

I am setting an alarm from my app, and when rebooting, I see I need to reset the alarm since it does not survive reboots. I created a broadcast receiver to receive BOOT_COMPLETED and this works so my manifest must be correct.

When I try this line of code below I get in trouble. I need to retrieve the time that I need to set the alarm to but it looks like I cannot access the prefs of my app (called S) because my app has never started. `NullPointerException` :

```
if ( S.prefs.getBoolean(S.SCHEDULEDSTATUS, false) == true ) { }
```

I suppose it should be obvious that I cannot read a public static final of an activity that has not been created.

Do I have to store my alarm time in a file or am I missing something here?

Comment: Posting up some code might help you get a good answer

Comment: The one line of code you see causes a NullPointerException. It is the first line of code in my receiver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to access it via the context you get in your reciever:

```
    public void onReceive(Context con, Intent intent) {

            final SharedPreferences settings = con.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);

    boolean boolValue = settings.getBoolean(BOOL, false);
}
```